# A SQL query that replaces null values.

Tags: sql, null

I need a SQL query that returns ContactDate, SortName, City, ContactType, and Summary from the tables below. If any value is null, I need it to return the text “No Entry”.

**ContactTable**

- *ContactID*
- ContactDate
- UserID
- Summary
- ContactType
- SortName

**UserTable**

- *UserID*
- FirstName
- LastName
- AddressID

**AddressTable**

- *AddressID*
- City
- Street
- State
- Zip

Comment: MS SQL 2000 ultimately going to crystal reports 8.0

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SELECT COALESCE(CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ContactTable.ContactDate, 101) AS VARCHAR(10)), 'No Entry') AS ContactDate,
       COALESCE(ContactTable.SortName, 'No Entry') AS SortName,
       COALESCE(AddressTable.City, 'No Entry') AS City,
       COALESCE(ContactTable.ContactType, 'No Entry') AS ContactType
FROM ContactTable
LEFT OUTER JOIN UserTable ON ContactTable.UserID = UserTable.UserID
LEFT OUTER JOIN AddressTable ON UserTable.AddressID = AddressTable.AddressID
```

[Here](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLDateTimeFormats.aspx) is a chart of SQL DateTime formats for the CONVERT statement above.

Comment: This will throw cast exceptions on the date.

Answer (score 8):

COALESCE() on any platform that is worth its weight in salt.

Make sure to handle casting issues.

Such as:

```
--(SQL Server)
SELECT
  C.ContactID,
  COALESCE(CAST(CONVERT(varchar(10), C.ContactDate, 101) AS varchar(10), 'No Entry') AS ContactDate,
  COALESCE(SorName, 'No Entry') AS SortName
```

etc., etc.

Comment: This is the only answer so far that has taken into account the fact that you need to cast you non-varchar columns back to varchar to use with coalesce/isnull.

Comment: You're missing a close paren after your second varchar(10).  We both lose for sloppiness!  ;-)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I get for typing it in the answer box :)

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT 
  ISNULL(ContactDate, 'No Entry') AS ContactDate
FROM Table
```

Using ISNULL is pretty simple.

Comment: This code will bomb out if ContactDate is null though. "Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string." You need to cast to varchar.

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle version of this function is called `nvl`. Same usage -- `SELECT nvl(col_name, desired_value) FROM foo`.

The more general version of this is `decode`, which has three parameters and allows you to specify which column value you want to perform a replacement for (so you can replace all 'Johnny' with 'John' or something).

Answer (score 0):

Using '**IIF**' is an Access DB solution but may work in other DBs.

```
SELECT IIF(IsNull(Foo), 'No Entry' ,Foo), IIF(IsNull(Bar), 'No Entry' ,Bar) From TableName
```

The function IIF returns one of 2 values depends of the evaluation of an expression.
SQL Syntax:
      IIF( expression, true-value1, false-value )

Answer (score 0):

You can also make different calls for each column.  It will take more individual calls, but it may be faster if you don't have many rows to update.

```
update ContactTable
set ContactDate = 'No Entry'
where ContactDate is null;
```

Repeat for each column.